Authenticate with SharePoint REST API using Azure AD not Azure ACS
With Python 2.7, I am currently trying to authenticate with the SharePoint REST API i.e. https://[tenant]/sites/[site_collection]/_api/web/lists, etc. I am able to generate, from what I can tell is, a valid token. However, when I go to use the token in my GET request, I keep getting a 401 Unauthorized. It seems that I need a self-signed certificate as well as the client ID and client secret in order to use the SharePoint REST API versus the Graph API. My problem is passing the certificate.
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/develop-applications-that-use-sites-selected-permissions-for-spo/ba-p/3790476
Token:
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "nonce": "gBi6Qid1tpqM2VqBOdLHDkWPWyCsjP9cfufaZWkl04w",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "MGLqj98VNLoXaFfpJCBpgB4JaKs",
  "kid": "MGLqj98VNLoXaFfpJCBpgB4JaKs"
}.{
  "aud": "[tenant]",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/[tenant_id]/",
  "iat": 1721855441,
  "nbf": 1721855441,
  "exp": 1721859341,
  "aio": "[...]",
  "app_displayname": "[app_name]",
  "appid": "[app_id]",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/[tenant_id]/",
  "idtyp": "app",
  "oid": "[...]",
  "rh": "[...]",
  "roles": [
    "Sites.Selected"
  ],
  "sid": "[...]",
  "sub": "[...]",
  "tid": "[tenant_id]",
  "uti": "[...]",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "xms_idrel": "7 28"
}.[Signature]

Script:
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, requests, certifi, json, urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings()

token_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant_id]/oauth2/v2.0/token'

url = sys.argv[1]

client_id = sys.argv[2] + '@[tenant_id]'
client_secret = sys.argv[3]

scope = 'https://[tenant]/.default'

data = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials', 'client_id': client_id, 'client_secret': client_secret, 'scope': scope}

cacert = '/usr/local/bin/ca.pem'
cert_path = '/usr/local/bin/server.pem'
key_path = '/usr/local/bin/key.pem'

access_token_response = requests.post(token_url, data=data, verify=False, allow_redirects=False, auth=(client_id, client_secret))

tokens = json.loads(access_token_response.text)

api_call_headers = {'X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED':'f','Authorization': 'Bearer ' + tokens['access_token']}

api_call_response = requests.get(url, headers=api_call_headers, timeout=1200, verify=cacert, cert=(cert_path, key_path))

if(api_call_response.status_code == 200):
  sys.stdout.write(api_call_response.content)
else:
  sys.stdout.write(str(api_call_response.status_code) + ', ' + api_call_response.reason)
  sys.exit(api_call_response.status_code)

I have tried just passing the certificate path in the verify parameter, just passing the certificate path in the cert parameter, passing the certificate path and the key path as a tuple in the cert parameter, and passing the certificate authority path in the verify parameter and the certificate path and the key path as a tuple in the cert parameter. None of those worked. Before upgrading to Python 3.8 and installing the MSAL library, I wanted to ask here if anyone knew a way to accomplish as things are currently.

Could you please edit the question by sharing the complete message?
